# Forward incoming ssh request to different ports

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I need to forward incoming ssh requests, if possible like this:

sshRequest arrives at server public Ip at port 21 (if possible it provides an extra field ID)
sshRequest is forwarded to localhost or internal IP on different port (same as ID).

The idea is to have reverse tunneling initiated from the client and I could ssh into localhost using different id´s and access different terminals depending on the id/port used.

Can someone properly explain me how to achieve this behaviour if my idea is not the good path to achieve it, or if it is, how can it be implemented?

Comment: Look into ssh option -L. It doesn't quite match your description but it is close enough that I see a good chance it'll fill your need. If not, feel free to update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, you want to have machines in the field connect to a central server that you can use to log into any one of them?

I once made something similar. You can just write a bash script that runs on the clients that does `ssh -R`, with or without `autossh`. You can then do magic on the server to match an IP address of the client to which port their listening on. This takes quite a bit of scripting through, combining the output of `ps` and `netstat` (and various options to both).

You can also have the client post the port somewhere to a simple PHP page after having established the tunnel, because contrary to the server, the client *does* know the listening port.

Comment: Yes that is the present situation. The magic point just vanished!! I was almost there, but needed your answer. 
I can update the data I need with the port and the id - don´t really need the ip. That way I can connect to the local port.
Thank you.

Comment: @CuriousMind I'm a bit unclear on whether you have all the info you need or not. If so, glad I could help.